# First project in Opencv to show image, error..

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

When I run opencv to show an image, I got an error like the image.

String index out of range: -8

The code is from Opencv website:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: how do you give the command argument (image path) ?

Answer (score 0):

Like it is mentioned in the tutorial, you need to call your program by command line with an argument which is the path to your image :

```
./DisplayImage HappyFish.jpg //From the tutorial
```

The arguments you pass to an application are stored in **argv** and counted by **argc**. The first parameter is always the path of your own application.

---

If this don't helps you, you'll need to show us some codes and logs (what is the exact error message, etc.)